# MySQL - Update user's data depending on other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, *users_steam* and *bets*.

in *users_steam* I save user data:
[image]

In *bets* I save player's bets (it's just a small portion):

[image]

Now the question is - what query should I be doing to add 2x the value of "**bet**" field in table *bets* to user's "**coins**" field in *users_steam* table IF "**horse**" is 4?

In this case the coins field should contain **600000** (100000x2 + 100000x2 + 100000x2)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE users_steam AS p
JOIN bets AS n ON p.steamid = n.steamid
SET n.complete = 1, p.coins = p.coins + n.bet*2
WHERE n.horse = 4;
```

But it updates "coins" field to **400000** (I think it ignores one row)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the inner query to get the sum and multiply it by 2, as shown below:

```
 update users_steam
 set coins = (
 select sum(bet)*2 from bets 
 where bets.steamid = users_steam.steamid
 and bets.horse = 4
);
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1116ff/1/0).

Comment: Oh right forgot to mention, yes they are connected with *steamid*

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly and attached SQL Fiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, how do I update the field "complete" so I know that this transaction is complete?

Comment: I guess 'complete' column resides in bets table. Do we have the list of users or something, for whom, we need to set this field?

Comment: After query checks the IF statements (steamid,horse=4), we need to update the row's field *complete* to 1

Comment: Updating both tables in a single query is not possible. We need to execute another update query on bets table with same horse id, user id and steam id that exists in users_steam table).